# Worklight Server V6.0 fails when IPv6 is enabled

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

The [Known Limitations for Worklight Server 6.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html?locale=en) document gives the following workaround in the last section, *Command Line Interface for IBM Worklight Developers fails when IPv6 is enabled*.

> 1. Open the directory for the Worklight Server, which is `/[USER_HOME]/.worklight/`.
> 2. Move to the directory for the default server, which is `/6.2.0/server/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/`.
> 3. Edit the `jvm.options` file that is located inside the opened directory.
>
>    - Add the following option to the end of this file: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
>    - Save and close the file.
> 4. Start or run the Worklight Server to verify that the problem is fixed.

Does this workaround also apply to earlier versions of Worklight such as 6.0 or 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Java 7 attempts to use IPv6 so to make sure the Worklight Server to start with an IPv4 address you have to update your `jvm.options` file with the following:

`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

So yes, the workaround http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_known_limitations.html?locale=en will work on previous versions.